# Cannot install GRASS GIS add-ons

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I am very new to GRASS GIS. I am trying to install an add-on (`r.bioclim`) but I get "`ERROR: 'svn' required. Please install 'svn' first`". I cannot understand how to install it (or even what it is), thus I am trying a simpler way, from the Settings (as shown here: https://grass.osgeo.org/download/addons/ ). But I cannot see any menu (see image attached) and if I type `r.bioclim` or `bioclim` in the search bar, nothing shows.
[image]
I also tried to find online the .zip of the extension but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It is a Python script, look at [grass_addon:r.bioclim)](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/grass8/src/raster/r.bioclim)

Comment: @gene thanks. I copied the script into a .py but I cannot open it using the Launch user-defined script. I opened the Python editor but it throws an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/lisa/GRASS/Prove/rbioclim.py", line 7, in
<module>
    import grass.script as grass
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/__init__.py", line
4, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six` I think I have to install this six, but I don't know how...

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include thanks or other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first error, you probably need git (or svn) installed on your computer. Next the `six` python package ( see [here](https://pypi.org/project/six/)) would probably be installed with `pip install six` or similar, depending on how python is installed on your system.

If you download the r.bioclim python script manually then you should place it into the standard directory for addon scripts:  `~/.grass8/addons/scripts/`.

HTH

Comment: In the end I didn't have the admin permissions, I got a sudoer to install the package for me.